# Validation on lead conversion's 'ISNEW' field

Tags: validation, leads

trying to create a validation rule to NOT let disqualified leads be converted WITH a new opportunity. Just attach into the existing account/contact.

I managed to research the validation rule components and it's around the ISNEW() field. Can you please review my code and help me find the error? It still lets users convert leads with new opps.

```
AND 
( 
ISNEW(), 
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Unqualified") 
)
```

Just to elaborate, it's this checkbox on the lead page that i'm talking about:
[image: Lead Button to Validate]

Comment: Under Setup>Customize>Leads>Lead Settings do you have the option "Require Validation for Converted Leads" checked?

Comment: Hey Todd, yes I do :) Csongor

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a Checkbox field lets say 'IsNotQualified' on Lead object and
   set the default value to **False**.
2. Create another checkbox field lets say 'IsLeadNotQualified' on
   Opportunity Object and set the value to **False**.
3. Map Custom Field IsQualified with IsLeadQualified.
4. Create a WF Rule on Lead Object with Evaluation Criteria as 'when a
   record is created, and every time it's edited'.
5. In WF Rule Criteria,Specify Lead status='Not Qualified' and add
   field update action and **set 'IsNotQualified' value to True** and
   Activate WF Rule.
6. Create A Validation Rule On Opportunity not on Lead Object:

   AND 
   ( 
   ISNEW(), 
   lightingintro__IsLeadQualified__c = TRUE 
   )

Instead of WF Rule You can also write a trigger on Before Insert of Lead and set the checkbox value to true.

Follow the steps and let me know if it helps.